# Accidental Turn On of Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We had a log file that wouldn't stop growing even though we do backups.  Turns out that replication had been turned on for that database.  None of us DBAs did that (at least as far as we know).  So, two questions.

1. Can you tell after the fact who or what turned on replication.  (We noticed that when we turned off replication there were no entries in the log.)
2. What operations can turn on replication WITHOUT the executioner (there's a better word for that) of the operation to know that they are turning on replication.

Thanks in advance.  We have fixed the problem but want to make sure it doesn't repeat itself.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: We are running 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

As for question 1, I don't think there's any way to know who enabled replication once you've torn it down. Even if it was still up, it'd be difficult (there is a login_name column in syssubscriptions that you might be able to use, for instance).

Speaking to point the second, the [documentation for sp_addpublication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188738.aspx) says you need either sysadmin or db_owner to enable replication.

Comment: Perhaps maybe ... ***maybe*** ... they'd be the owner of the replication jobs too?

Comment: If my environment is any indication, no. All of mine are owned by distributor_admin. Besides, a lot of times, tearing down replication will remove the jobs as well.

Comment: That's right. It's been a while since I've worked with replication. Thanks for the information.